# WCF RESTful Service - JSONP binding ( server closed the connection exception)

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, .net-4.0, jsonp

My project is having a WCF Web Service (.Net framework 4.0)  with JSONP binding for cross domain communications.

There are several methods in my service with several complex types using DataContract and DataMember properties.

**Issue** The problem that I am facing is:
When I am trying to call the service (running Visual Studio), I am able to get JSONP responses for several methods except one particular method which returns: ***Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without any response...***

Can anyone explain what I may b doing wrong or what configuration I may be missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Researched more on the issue. Found out that one of the DateTime object used in the method was having default assigned value: '01/01/0001'. Setting its value to Now.Date solved the issue